# Postsharp problems on teamcity

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, postsharp

We have a project trageting .net framework 4.0 and we are using postsharp. everything is working fine on my local machine but on our teamcity server we get the following error

```
00:44][MSBuild output] "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a26b6bf43590f451\Main\myproj.csproj" (default target) (4:2) ->
[16:00:44][MSBuild output] (PostSharp30 target) -> 
[16:00:44][MSBuild output]   unknown : error PS0219: The targeting pack for target platform ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" is either not installed or not properly registered. Please install the appropriate targeting pack. [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a26b6bf43590f451\Main\myproj.csproj]
[16:00:44][MSBuild output] 
[16:00:44][MSBuild output]     2 Warning(s)
[16:00:44][MSBuild output]     1 Error(s)
[16:00:44][MSBuild output] 
[16:00:44][MSBuild output] Time Elapsed 00:00:30.78
```

Comment: Just a guesswork: If you have just installed .NET framework 4.0 on build server then restart the server and try to trigger manual build otherwise install .NET framework 4.0 SDK on server.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting suggests that there is some problem with registration of .NET SDK's to MSBuild. PostSharp uses MSBuild calls to determine installed frameworks and fetch information about these. You can inspect what PostSharp "sees" by looking into `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\InstalledFrameworks` directory and on the latest XML file in there.

To solve this, please install Microsoft Build Tools 2013 on the build server. Then, while configuring a build step in TeamCity, please make sure that you have Microsoft Build Tools 2013 and MSBuild 12.0 selected. MSBuild from .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012) will also work.

Comment: Thank you, but i cant get it to work. i installed visual studio 2013 but are getting the same errors when i open the solution and try to build it there.

Comment: Could you please contact us on our support site and send the content of `InstalledFrameworks` directory and the build log?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a PostSharp error — your build agent probably just doesn't have the correct version of Visual Studio installed.  You can either install VS, or manually install the [appropriate targeting pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn250998) on your build agents.  (That link is for VS2013.  See the other links on that page if you're using other versions of VS.)

It may help to know that "targeting packs" in this context are also known as ".NET SDKs."

Comment: I would like add that the error is actually produced by PostSharp, which also means that the main compilation step has finished successfully. Maybe there's only .NET 4.5 SDK on the server and C# compiler was ok with it, even though the target is .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks, i have installed all the updates available for both .net 4.0 and 4.0.3 but i still get the same error.

Comment: Can this be an issue of x86 vs x86_x64 compability. the server is running x86_x64 but the failing step are trying the execute C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.15\bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x86.exe. there are a C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.15\bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x64.exe available in the same folder.

Comment: apparently this has nothing to do with teamcity, i installed visual studioexpress on the build server and im getting the same errors when i try to build inside visual studio